# Cannot set Azure Active Directory Admin in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I cannot set Azure Active Directory Admin in Azure SQL Database for myself.
[attached pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMcBr.png)

Comment: Looks like permission issue. Are you using the right AD account?

Answer (score 1):

To set the as the Azure Active Directory Admin in the Azure SQL Server : You have to have the Owner role or the Contributor:

> As, Azure AD is nothing but an identity store in Azure. Here we can
> define users, groups, applications, and service principles. These
> users can authenticate onto Azure and they can access resources that
> are part of Azure subscription.
>
> We can assign Azure AD roles to a user and these permissions are
> normally given to manage the various aspects of Azure AD.

Role-based access control (RBAC), on the other hand, is used to authorise a user to use Azure resources. ​

> For example, you might grant a user the ability to create a storage
> account or manage resource groups by assigning them a role.

At the management group, subscription, resource group, or resource level, role-based access control can be implemented.

RBAC has three basic roles that apply to all resource types:

- Owner: This role has full access to all the resources and can delegate
  access to others.
- Contributor: This role can create and manage all types of resources,
  but can’t grant access to other users and groups.
- Reader: This role can view existing Azure resources.

Here, is the way I am able to add, as the assigned role to me is `Contributor` Role.

[image]

Once you have the `Owner` or `Contributor` Role you will be able to add the Azure Active Directory Admin for the SQL server:

[image]